# find matches in files and parse out the line number

Tags: node.js

I am trying to find matches in files and parse out the line number and what was the match along with the file name. So far I am able to read the files from the directory / sub directories and then use `indexOf()` which in this case is not very efficient. The goal would be go through all the files and find matches for the following

```
.http(
.httpContinue(
$httpUrl(
httpURL
getHttpImageURL(
getHttpURL(
```

The code I have so far looks like this

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = [my directory];

function readFiles(dirname) {
  fs.readdir(dirname, function(err, filenames) {
    if (err) {
      return;
    }
    filenames.forEach(function(filename) {
        if (fs.lstatSync(dirname+'/'+filename).isDirectory() ){
            readFiles(dirname+'/'+filename);
        };
        fs.readFile(dirname+'/'+filename, { encoding: 'utf8' }, function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                return;
            }
            //This is not very effective and I need to check each line for all these possible matches

            if (content.indexOf('http(') > -1) {

                    if(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    }
                    console.log(filename);

            }
        });
    });
  });
}

readFiles(path);
```

The challenge I am facing is to read lines and parse line numbers where I found a match and what was the match. Cant figure out how to accomplish that.

Comment: You never mentioned a specific problem you are having with your code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this for your `if` statement

```
// This should really go somewhere near the top of the file
const wantedStrings = ['.http(',
                       '.httpContinue(',
                       '$httpUrl(',
                       'httpURL',
                       'getHttpImageURL(',
                       'getHttpURL('];


if (content.toLowerCase().includes('http') 
    && wantedStrings.filter(s => content.includes(s)).length > 0) {
        // Don't need another err check here
        console.log(filename);

}
```